# How to convert MST time zone to IST format and then want to persist that in database in java

Tags: java, mysql, timezone

I am new to Java. I have a web application that runs on a godaddy server in the USA.

The problem is when we use the application anywhere we need to update the date with the respective timestamp in database. While updating it is storing as MST format date instead of IST format (when I tried from India). Let me know how can I solve this.

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String date =  f.format(new Date());
Date aptDate = formatter.parse(date);
System.Out.Print("The IST time  is : "+ date);
```

Here I am getting the string format date, I want to convert into a date object and then store in the database.

When I apply the conversion it is giving earlier date. Let me what is the wrong going.

Comment: I'm confused! What exactly is the problem? It's a fact that MST *is earlier* than IST.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is confusing. Here are some guidelines to re-orient your thinking.

You are using old date-time classes now outmoded by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Avoid the old classes as they are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

Stop using the 3-4 letter codes such as `IST`. Do you mean India Standard Time or Irish? These codes are neither standardized nor unique. Erase these codes from both your thinking and your code. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region`.

Do most of your work, your business logic, data exchange, data storage, and database in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Apply a time zone only when expected by your user or data sink.

Use [date-time types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) when defining columns in your database. Do not store date-time values as strings.

Use the java.sql types to transfer date-time values in and out of the database. Convert immediately to java.time types. Eventually JDBC drivers will be updated to use java.time types directly. Until that day, use new methods added to the old java.sql classes for convenient conversions.

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Convert to java.sql.Timestamp to write to the database.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( now );
```

To the other direction, for retrieval, convert from java.sql to java.time.

```
Instant instant = myJavaSqlTimestamp.toInstant();
```

Notice that for database work we do not care about time zone as the values are all **in UTC on all sides**: Java, JDBC, SQL, database.

To view the [wall-clock time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for some locality, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to generate a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zoneIdEdmonton = zoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" );
ZonedDateTime zdtEdmonton = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneIdEdmonton );
```

You can apply yet another time zone. Note that java.time uses immutable objects. An new object arises from an old object rather than changing (“mutating”) the original. In this example, the `zdtEdmonton` object begets the `zdtKolkata` object.

```
ZoneId zoneIdKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdtEdmonton.withZoneSameInstant( zoneIdKolkata );
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and reply Mr.Basil Bourque.